# Subtract one cell from the cell above in Spotfire using multiple columns

Tags: calculated-columns, spotfire

How would I create a calculated column that would find the thickness of a cell that is the difference from one cell with the cell above it, but want to do this for many individual wells that have unique identifiers in a column. Additional, the last cell of that well will not have a value because there is not cell below it. On top of that I would like to play with the option of calculating this from deepest to shallowest, or shallowest to deepest so c in a column, and organized by ranking scheme (ascending or descending).

See image attached

[image]

Comment: Hey @Lgeo, you said there are some unique identifiers in a column, can you post those to the sample data (ideally as text vs image)? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use a calculated column with an OVER statement (provided you're not using an in-database data connection). It will look like this:

```
Sum([Depth]) OVER Intersect([Well],Next([Depth])) - [Depth]
```

It will return the same result regardless of the row order because the Next function has built-in alphanumeric sorting which it performs on [Depth].